# How to keep numbers only from user input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I found this and I don't know whether it is a function or what and I can't understand what it does

`(/^\d+$/)`

Comment: Thats a regex expression

Comment: can you explain it?

Comment: @MarcoMaher theres plenty of tutorials online explaining regex.

Comment: @DanielA.White I thought it is something easy .. anyway I will google it

Comment: Regular expressions allow you to extract and restrict certain things from strings or inputs,  if you wanted a string without any `a`'s. You could also find all instances of a string or letter or pattern then replace them etc.

Comment: `I thought it is something easy` translation ... i thought i wouldnt have to do the work of thinking about it.

Answer (score 6):

It's a Regular Expression AKA [**RegExp** <sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
(/^\d+$/)
```

`()` Are simple brackets (from a function call using RegExp as argument)

`/ ... /` is a Regex syntax matching:
`^`  from the start of a string
`\d` match numbers (akin to `[0-9]`)
`+`  one or more times
`$`  till the end of string

Answer (score 2):

```
/ : js regex delimiter

^ : start of the string

\d: matches any single digit between 0 - 9

+ : multiple time and at least once

$ : end of the string

/ : Js regex delimiter
```

This means in summary match a string that contains only digit, once or multiple time. Example : "7" is valid, "77" is valid, "" is not valid